# Ruby Mechanize Outlook Web Access

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am trying to use ruby mechanize to access specific emails from my outlook web access account.

I am using the following code.

```
    require 'mechanize'
    require 'logger'

    a = Mechanize.new
    a.cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies.new)
    a.log = Logger.new('log1.log') 

    a.get('htts://webmail.xxxxxxx.org/') do |page|

      my_page = page.form_with(:action => '/owa/auth.owa') do |f|
        f.username  = "------------"
        f.password  = "------------"
      end.click_button

      #a.cookie_jar.load('cookies.yml')

      a.get('https://webmail.xxxxxxx.org/owa/Inbox/?Cmd=contents&Page=1') do |p|
          file = File.new("new.xml","w+")
          file.puts p.parser.to_xml
          file.close
      end

   end
```

Why is this code not working?

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working OWA retrieval script using nokogiri and mechanize to a SSL owa exchange website.

It requires rubygems, mechanize (+deps), and highline to be installed.

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'mechanize'
    require 'logger'
    require 'highline/import'

    @url = 'https://email.***.***/Exchange'

    @mechanize = Mechanize.new { |a| a.log = Logger.new('./log1.log') }

    #In case you dont have trusted certs
    @mechanize.agent.http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    @mechanize.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
    @mechanize.keep_alive = 'enable'

    username = ask("Enter your username: ")
    domain = ask("Enter your domain: ")
    password = ask("Enter your password: ") {|q| q.echo = "*" }

    @mechanize.get(@url) do |page|

      form = page.forms[0]

      form["username"] = domain + '\\' + username
      form["password"] = password
      page = form.submit 
    end

    ## Common Mailbox Schemes
    @mailbox = "#{username}"

    # @mailbox = "#{username}@#{domain}.#{tld}"
    # @mailbox = "#{username}@#{domain}"

    @inbox = @url + "/#{@mailbox}/Inbox/?Cmd=contents&Page=1&View=Unread%20Messages"

    inboxlisting = @mechanize.get(@inbox) do |page|

      fragment = Nokogiri::HTML(page.body)
      ["//img[@src='/exchweb/img/icon-msg-unread.gif']"].each do |xpathq|
        puts "Found #{fragment.xpath(xpathq).count} new emails."
      end  

      ["//img[@src='/exchweb/img/icon-mtgreq.gif']"].each do |xpathq|
           puts "Found #{fragment.xpath(xpathq).count} new meeting requests."
      end  

    end
```

Example Script Output:

```
    $ ruby ./owa.rb 
    Enter your username: john.doe
    Enter your domain: mywork
    Enter your password: ************
    Found 31 new emails.
    Found 3 new meeting requests.
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the purpose of usage and question, but it may be better to use Capybara with Selenium to access this site?